non-root command line operations can't connect to mariadb
I'm using mariadb 15.1 on Ubuntu 22.04
I'm running a bunch of webapplications that require a mysql server. Each of the hosted apps is having on issue interacting with mariadb.
However, if I try to import, export or inspect a database using the commandline, I get this:
"ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)"
/tmp/mysql.sock doesn't exist on this system.

There is no mariadb 15.1.  if you do get connected, do `select version()' to see the server version

You say non-root doesn't work, does that mean you can connect as root?  Are you even running the server?

@ysth: yes, the server is running. I can connect if I am root on the system.

/tmp/mysql.sock is the default socket location for non-packaged based systems.
Ubuntu/Debian defaults to /run/mysqld/mysqld.sock.
If in doubt, look at the logs for the mariadb.service with journalctl -n 40 -u mariadb.service where it logs the location where the socket it created.
Perhaps you have /tmp/mysql.sock in a configuration file under /etc/mysql or elsewhere that is incorrect.

I haven't touched the configurations for mariadb.
The connection failure has been recent and sudden. Possibly a side-effect of an update either to the mariadb server or the operating system itself.
But in any case, I can still connect as normal if I'm logged in as root.
The issue is that the non-root user gets the error.

permission error for non-root on config file, or path to the socket or config file (specifying socket). Include in question \s when you do connect as root.
